# How to empty the input box after submitting it in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have only one input field and on submitting it i want to empty it.Can any one suggest me help..

my template,

```
 <form class="nobottommargin" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" novalidate="novalidate">
  <textarea class="required sm-form-control" [formControl]="form.controls['comment']"  placeholder="Comment...."></textarea>
    <div class="form-group">
       <button class="button" type="submit" >Enter</button>
    </div> 
 </form>
```

my ts,

```
onSubmit(form):any{
      form.commemt = '';
}
```

Comment: You should be using `ngModel` here, not sure why you're using `[formGroup]` and `[formControl]`. Just add a property to your component, and in your textarea do `[(ngModel)]="theproperty"`. Then you can clear or set it simply by setting the property.

Answer (score 0):

As already specified you should be using `[(ngModel)]=""` to bind data to form controls

```
<form class="nobottommargin" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #myForm="ngForm">
  <textarea class="required sm-form-control" [(ngModel)]="myFormValues?.comment" name="myTextArea" placeholder="Comment...."></textarea>
    <div class="form-group">
       <button class="button" type="submit" >Enter</button>
    </div> 
 </form>
```

Then your `onSubmit()` function should work properly

```
// The values to be bound to the form
myFormValues: any = {
    "comment": 'Default Value'
}

// The submit function can then access the 2-way bound values
onSubmit():void {
      // Do what you need to before reseting the values

      // Reset values for next time
      this.myFormValues.comment = '';
}
```

Here is the link to the [**Angular 2 Forms**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) guide.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are using the ReactiveFormsModule and a FormGroup you need to call something more like what is below.

The object you are passing in is a simple {Key: Value} listing of your form controls which does not actually tie back to your form object. To do so, it looks to see if it has a control by the Key name in the simple object that is represented by form.value and then sets the value via setValue to blank. Note that you can also pass in just form as your argument from the HTML template and it is the FormGroup object itself instead of the simpler KVP object.

```
onSubmit(form):any{
  for(var prop in form) {
    if(this.form.controls.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      this.form.controls[prop].setValue('');
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a working Plunkr (note that having it return false prevents a page reload): http://plnkr.co/edit/oGCsZr?p=preview

Comment: If you're not stuck on a given version of angular and your package.json is set up correctly then run the command npm update -S which will update your packages to the latest versions and save them as your new baseline.

If you are tied to a particular version then import FormControl and do a cast to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewChild :

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
//.......

export class YourPage {
@ViewChild('commentContent') commentContent;

postComment(post) {
//.....
// after success
  this.commentContent.setValue('');
}
```

html

```
 <textarea ... #commentContent></textarea>
```